# How many (balanced) BST can be generated from a sorted list

Tags: binary-search-tree

is there a generalized formula that can calculate the number of (balanced) BST can be generated from a sorted list, like (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)?  Thanks.

Comment: A BST can be full or complete but not balanced.What exactly you mean by balanced? You need to add additional definition to this. Like RB, AVL